# Need a equivalent solution for vbscript command cdbl(now) with php

Tags: php, vbscript

With vbscript i can retrieve a double value from the current date/time with the command `cdbl(now)`.

```
Now = '09.05.2015 21:44:10'
cdbl(Now) = 42133,9056712963
```

I'm looking for a equivalent solution with php that will give me back a double value from the current date/time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function returns the current Unix timestamp as a double value:

```
function cdblnow(){
    // time in seconds since 1 Jan 1970 (GMT)
    $timeunix = time();
    // add the timezone offset
    $TimeZone = "Asia/Bangkok";
    $dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($TimeZone);
    $dateTime = new DateTime("now", $dateTimeZone);
    $timeOffset = $dateTimeZone->getOffset($dateTime);
    $timeunix = $timeunix + $timeOffset;
    // determines the days between 1 Jan 1970 and today
    $days = intval($timeunix / 86400);
    // second count from today
    $secondsremains = $timeunix % 86400;
    // 25569 days difference between microsoft and unix time stamp start
    $now_date = $days + 25569;
    // 0.0000115741 represents one second at the cdbl-function from microsoft
    $now_time = $secondsremains * 0.0000115741;
    return $now_date + $now_time;}
```

This function returns the unix time stamp from a double:

```
function GetUnixTimeFromCdblNow($cdbl){
$days = intval($cdbl);
$seconds = round($cdbl - $days,9);
$timeunix = (($days -25569) * 86400);
$timeunix = $timeunix + intval($seconds / 0.0000115740);
return $timeunix;}
```

Answer (score 0):

cdbl return datetime in microsoft format. before comma date - number of days since 1 January 1900. After comma time - 24 hours is 1. So if you use dates within Unix epoch (code may be not effective,i wanted make it more understandable)

```
function cdbl($str) {
    $datetime0 = new DateTime('1970-01-01');
    $datetime = new DateTime($str);
// 25560 - days from 1 Jan 1900 to 1 Jan 1970
    $cdbl = $datetime->diff($datetime0)->days + 25569;

// Remove time from string  - it is the sane as 00:00
    $str0 = preg_replace('/((T|\s+).+)$/','', $str);
// The number of seconds since the day start
    $time = strtotime($str) - strtotime($str0);
// The number of seconds wittin a day
    $timefullday = strtotime("$str0 + 1 day") - strtotime($str0);
    $cdbl += $time / $timefullday;
    return $cdbl;
}
echo cdbl('09.05.2015 21:44:10');
```

result:

```
42133.905671296
```

As you can see, there is a problem of rounding. If print result of the calculation time before summing, the answer will be the same as yours. I've never done calculating tasks, so I can not tell you what to do with it. The only suggestion is convert to a string :)

Well, if you choose to work outside of Unix dates you should write some code

Comment: How to change the function to not pass and use a formatted date string inside the function? I just want that the function uses the php func time() to get the current date/time value, convert it and give it back. Same behavior like at vbscript with cdbl(now)).

Comment: How you think to call the function. There is not function now() in php. Ask cbbl(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) - it is the same. By the way, if answer is helpful, don't forget  accept it :)

Comment: Or define function now()  `{ return date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); }` Than you can call `cdbl(now())`

Comment: php have the func time() similar to cdbl(now)). so its not necessary to send a date formatted string to your function to get the current time. i just want call the function without any parameters and get back the converted value. i just try to avoid the overhead with formatted date strings.

Comment: What's a problem? say as first line of function `$str = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $str);`